# CQS file & namespace organization

Tags: orm, architecture

I have a very large solution made of over 50 projects (windows services, web sites, class libraries) that has been built using a framework of services & repositories and using the Telerik DataAccess ORM. After very long discussions with architects from Telerik the above design was suggested by them as it should have fit our needs at the time and provide a testable framework of code. A few years later, now our services classes have grown to be thousands of lines long making them harder to maintain and test.

Upon reading and researching on a few problems in our code, I came across CQS (Command Query Separation) which makes more sense to me in our project as it will divide our huge service classes into smaller testable classes. I have successfully implemented a small prof of concept of this but I am now wondering how will my code be organized when I move 1000+ queries into the CQS namespace (concentrating on queries now as commands I imagine will be organized the same)- obviously putting all queries, handlers and results each in their own folder and each folder will have 1000+ files will be a huge pain to find something.

So far I have have this folder structure

```
    Model
        Customer
    Queries
        CustomerNameByIdQuery
        CustomerNameByTextSearchQuery
    QueryHandlers
        CustomerNameByIdQueryHandler
        CustomerNameByTextSearchQueryHandler
    QueryResults
        CustomerNameQueryResult
```

Both queries return the same `CustomerNameQueryResult` which has only Id and Value properties

Now imaging I need to query the full customer record as well so I would need a `CustomerByIdQuery`, `CustomerByIdQueryHandler` and a result from the Model of `Customer`. And currently there are about 10 other queries over customer with different parameters for different needs.

This pattern over hundreds of tables will make a lot of query classes and handlers making it really hard to find what I need to use at a specific place in code (promoting code re-use if possible).

I'm looking for advise from veterans who have been using CQS in a big production app about the organization of the namespaces/files of the queries in your project as for how is your solution organized for queries/handlers/results? For example do you put the query & handler in the same file? Separate files is separate directories? What do you do with multiple queries over the same object? Single file holding all queries or multiple files? Do you divide queries with namespaces for easier coding? Are there any problems you are aware of with your structure?

I know that there is no single "correct" answer here but some advise from people who have been using this methodology over time would help me and others from falling into whatever problems you already encountered and solved in the file/folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

We don't use CQS but we have a big solution with many projects and one of the projects is the repository layer.

We have a repository class per model so following your example we try to let all queries relative to the **Customer Model** in the **Customer Repository**.
In fact this comes from the Model/Proxy/Service/Repository architecture in layers we utilize.
The trick part comes with things like **Contacts**. We have that model and that repository full of queries using Contacts table.
So where the Contacts from Customeres query lies? It depends on the functionality really it's a functionatily of the Customer so it was placed in the Customer Repository. Note we can select the Customer and in a loop call the Contacts for each one but in general we avoid due to performance problems.

Relative to the many GetCustomerXXX methods.

Yeah we already got that many methods we also have overloads of same methods to allow more fine searchs using lots of differente parameters and also a Paged Query Wraper so we can have a search screen loads a bit each time the users scrolls down (so we change the answer depending how you ask). All those queries lies in the Customer repository.

Relative to Domain organization.

Each Model can be used by many functionalities in any Project/Domain. For example the Customer lies in the Core domain and the Bills in the Financial domain. Of course you can query all Bills from a Customer so the Customer Model can be used by any project/Domain. All projects using Customers and Bills will have those same domains and almost the same folder hyerarchy.

Resume:
We have a Models projects it's referenced by all other projects. It contains many domains and also a complex folder hyerarchy.

All projects (except service and repository) references the proxy Project and the proxy references the service and the service references the repository.

That way we don't get circular references, manage complexity and keep sanity.
Note (some UI projects using the proxies are even in different languages and are used to implement different user experiences (web/winform/remote/offline).

**Edit**

Some services can grow to resemble monolithc monsters. IMHO anything over 300 lines is big and some services grows up to more than 2k lines.

One factor helped us a lot is where already build base classes to handle the most common scenarios.

For example we have a `IEnumarebale<BaseModel> GetAll(GenericFilter filter)` method in the very repository base class so that means all Models do implement that automaticaly.
In fact most of the repositoy classes are empty because the basic was already covered and we need to code only custom logic.

Also we avoid to call repositories from another service, in general services calls services thus avoiding almost any code duplication. For example the Base Crud Class has CustomValidation method and Before/After Insert/Delete/Update events we can override as needed.

Following the previous example. Both Customer and Contacts have their CustomValidation. Inserting a new Customer (with Contacts) will automatic call both validations.

All automatized tests calls the base methods saving a lot of time.

Comment: Jean, thanks for the elaborated answer. You are basically describing my current architecture. The "problem" with it is that the services grow to be very long as they encompass many different repositories connected to the same problem domain. That is what I was trying to simplify with CQS (which should split up the services into small chunks)

Comment: @DaniAvni See my edit using Base Classes helped a lot to minimize service and in especial repository. Some Services are complex and services calls other models services, we try to avoid calling other repositories.

Comment: Jean, We also try not to call services from other services and for most of our code it's working. Still My services are huge. for example my tasks service has CRUD methods for tasks, CRUD for task types, methods for booking tasks and lots of other methods resulting in a huge file 3K+ lines if I remember correctly. It's these files I try to break with CQS and since every method in my service will translate into a command or query it should make the huge file break into smaller manageable chunks

Comment: That little difference is crucial. Task service CRUD will call TaskType service whit all logic for CRUD and validations that way Task service can be smaller and still testable passing responsabilities to the TaskType service. Anyway you looks like to be in the right path.

Comment: Maybe it's a difference of terms. Our services are not per entity. The would make me create 100+ services. Instead services are per "area of concern" i.e. the tasks service has all things that are task related (tasks, task types, task skills, booking etc). The downside is that each service is very large as it holds among other things CRUD for multiple types of entities.

Comment: @DaniAvni We do have many hundreds services, repositories, etc one for each model but models and everything lies in "area of concern" each AoC lies in a folder || folder hyerarchy

Comment: following up on your great explanation - if you have hundreds of services how does your web site consume them? Do you have a service hub? or do the web site create an instance of what ever services it needs?

Comment: @DaniAvni Both! the services are not called directly we have a proxy layer for that and the proxies are instantiated by demand. Each proxy auto instantiates all services it's needs to call any of it's methods. Each proxy is correlated to one functionality

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I took a different approach.  Instead, I grouped everything by Feature.  Since each Model (Request/Response) was tied directly to the handler, I put them all in the same folder.  Since each query needs to be specific to the query/command you are running, too, I just put the repository that backs it in the same folder, too.  So the way I would have structured your example:

Model
Customer
Features
Queries
CustomerNameById
CustomerNameByIdQuery
CustomerNameByIdQueryHandler
CustomerNameByIdQueryResult
CustomerNameByText
CustomerNameByTextSearchQuery
CustomerNameByTextSearchQueryHandler
CustomerNameByTextSearchResult

However, if Id/Text ended up returning the exact same thing, I probably would combine the two and just change the Query/Request to support both filters at the same time.  Nothing wrong with that.  In my experience, the query you are writing is for a specific front-end piece that is showing the results in a specific way.

I also use decorators heavily in my CQS projects, so if you have validation or mapping or whatever, those can also go inside that same subfolder.  That way, everything that is specific to the query/command at hand is in the same folder.  If it needs an external reference, you'd IoC inject that shared component and you'd still be good to go.